# Suspend/Hibernate broken on Macbook Pro 10.1 retina with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, power-management, suspend, macbook

I installed *Ubuntu 13.04* on my *Macbook Pro 10.1* with *Retina* display using [this](http://randomtutor.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-ubuntu-on-retina-macbook-pro.html) tutorial. Then I upgraded to 13.10. Everything works great and I really enjoy Ubuntu except for one issue. Whenever I close the lid of my laptop, or manually enter suspend or hibernate my computer is unable to boot back up. Hibernate usually just boots to a black screen and Suspend sometimes lets me see the login screen but I can't click on anything or type. I always end up having to force shutdown my system and reboot.

I read about other people with a similar problem who usually fix it by installing proprietary graphics drivers but every time I try that it makes it so I can't boot up at all. It just boots to a completely dark screen and I have to restore my operating system.

This issue is important because I can't be constantly rebooting my machine every time I close it and if I set it to do nothing when I close the lid the battery dies very fast.

Comment: Have you looked at `/var/log/pm-*.log*`? It's where suspend/resume information is logged. Also read  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html and add descriptions of "manually enter suspend or hibernate", "boots to a completely dark screen and I have to restore my operating system". Details!!

Comment: By manually enter suspend or hibernate I mean - When I select suspend from the shut down menu. I mean this as an alternative to just shutting the lid. By boots to a completely dark screen I mean - it boots up normally, I see the text on the screen that I normally do but instead of going to the login screen the screen just shuts off and I can't do anything but I can see that the keyboard back light is still on. I will check the log file in a few hours.

Comment: When I start suspend from the shutdown options menu and after I reboot once the screen doesn't turn on, the log file contains [this](http://pastebin.com/N52Qc11z) @waltinator

Comment: What happens when you hint Enter on your dark screen? Ctrl-Alt-F1 ?

Comment: @waltinator Nothing happens when I do either of those things. I tested waking up from hibernate and it opens up a login screen but I can't click on anything or type anything, Ctrl-Alt-F1 doesn't work either. Eventually the screen goes black.

Comment: I'm using this graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB. With this driver: Gallium 0.4 on NVE7

Comment: Did you notice lines 129-30 and 143-144 of the log you posted? Investigate the `Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video: 22: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video: shopt: not found`

Comment: @waltinator I did not notice that. I also upgraded to 13.10 and the issue persists. The log file again contains the lines you pointed out. I found a bug report concerning those lines but it claims that it was fixed in the most recent release of pm-utils. However I already had the most recent version of that package.

Comment: With the upgrade when I suspend the screen will come back on and I can move my mouse but I can't click on anything or type so I still have to force shutdown. This is the new log file - http://pastebin.com/ErT5z2LV.

Comment: You've changed the playing field! This is no longer about "...Ubuntu 13.04". Please fix your question.

Comment: I guess you're going to have to read `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README.debugging` and set PM_DEBUG="true". Can you figure out which of the power management scripts causes you to lose your keyboard and your nouse?

Comment: @waltinator I changed the question acordingly. I turned on debugging and it outputted [this](http://pastebin.com/0NtwqAux). I looked through it but I couldn't glean any information from it. How might I go about figuring that out?

Comment: I found a few interesting lines in your logfile:  

`48 + before_hooks`  
`49 + [ -z uswsusp_hooks ]`  
`50 + local meth`  
`51 + command_exists uswsusp_hooks`  
`52 + type uswsusp_hooks`  
`53 + return 0`  
`54 + uswsusp_hooks`  
`55 + disablehook 99video disabled by uswsusp`  
`56 + echo disabled by uswsusp`  

I don't have `uswsusp` installed, but it is "userspace software suspend" and may be interfering.

And, I noticed that `uswsusp` has disabled `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video`. This seems strange. Use `dpkg -L uswsusp` to list the files in the package, and see what it does.

Comment: @waltinator It seems like it provides some alternate suspend function. I removed the package with apt-get. I get the same problem but the lines you mention disappear. [This](http://pastebin.com/uyRy0xqj) is the new log file.

Comment: I'm stumped. You keep making changes without understanding how the change relates to the problem. Good luck.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you for all your help. You're right, I don't understand any of this. Where would I start learning how to deal with these problems myself?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to kernel  3.13.0-031300rc6-generic seems to have fixed the issue. It also installed the Intel® Ivybridge Mobile driver which may be related to the fix. There are a few minor graphics artifacts but other than that everything works fine.